# Rails Fixnum Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple query that Rails seems to be interpreting as a fixnum, but I'm not sure why.  My code looks like this:

```
@user_with_points = Point.select("sum(points) as points, user_id").order("points desc").group("user_id")
@user_with_points.each_with_index do |user_with_point, index|
```

When I add `puts @user_with_points`, it shows:

```
#<Point:0x6360138>
#<Point:0x6322f38>
```

However, I'm receiving this error this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for 75:Fixnum
```

**adding Entire Code**

```
def self.update_overall_rank_and_points
  @user_with_points = Point.select("sum(points) as points, user_id").order("points desc").group("user_id")
  rank = 0
  points = 0

  @user_with_points.each_with_index do |user_with_point, index|           
    @user = User.find(user_with_point.user_id)
    if user_with_point.points != points
      points = user_with_point.points
      rank += 1
    end
    @user.rank = rank
    @user.points = user_with_point.points
    @user.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
@user_with_points = Point.sum(:points, :group => :user_id, :order => 'sum(points)')
@user_with_points.each do |user_id, points|
  #...
  user = User.find(user_id)
  if user.points != points
    puts "not equal!"
  end
end
```

Comment: When I do this, it gets me past the error with the "each", but I receive a similar error on this `if user_id.points != points` in my code.  I pasted my entire original code above and the modified version here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/predict_images/points+fixnum+error.PNG

Comment: @yellowreign, Nope, the `sum` return a hash, `user_id` is the id of the user, which is an integer.

Comment: I'm still getting "NoMethodError: undefined method 'points' for 1:Fixnum after changing `points = user_with_point.points
      and rank += 1` to `puts "not equal!"`

Comment: @yellowreign There is no `user_with_point` in my code. What you should do is `user.points = points`

Comment: Thanks.  The problem I'm running into is that there are three meanings for points: (1) the current points the user record has (2) the points from the query (which is what user.points should be set to) and (3) and the points variable that keeps track of how many points for a given rank (initiated as 0 in the code).  So the two issues I'm running into are: (a) user.points is never equal to points so the rank always goes up (b) when I rename the points variable I'm using for purpose (3) above, I get 'undefined method 'each' for 75:Fixnum (75 is the points sum).  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like the issue was because `User.rb` had `has_many :points`

Answer (score 2):

Your query is returning a scalar value which the sum of points as an integer.  The total of your query happens to be 75, hence the error. Therefore you can't do an `each` against it since it's not an enumeration.